# How do I get a unique count of the root record, not the children records?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to get a total count of how many patients that are inactive with equipment associated to them. The following returns a value of 4.  It needs to return a value of 1 since there is 1 patient that is inactive with 4 pieces of equipment.

```
return FluentSessionManager.GetSession()
            .CreateCriteria<Patients>()
            .CreateAlias("Locations", "l")
            .CreateAlias("l.Branches", "b")
            .CreateAlias("PatientsEquipment", "pe")
            .Add(Expression.Eq("b.ID", branchID))
            .Add(Expression.Eq("CurrentStatus", Enumerations.PatientStatus.Inactive))
            .Add(Expression.IsNull("pe.PickupDate"))
            .Add(Expression.Eq("pe.PickupRequestSent", false))
            .Add(Expression.Eq("pe.MaintenanceRequestSent", false))
            .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
            .SetProjection(Projections.Count("ID")).UniqueResult<int>();
```

I can get an accurate count if I do the following:

```
            ICriteria query = FluentSessionManager.GetSession()
            .CreateCriteria<Patients>()
            .CreateAlias("Locations", "l")
            .CreateAlias("l.Branches", "b")
            .CreateAlias("PatientsEquipment", "pe")
            .Add(Expression.Eq("b.ID", branchID))
            .Add(Expression.Eq("CurrentStatus", Enumerations.PatientStatus.Inactive))
            .Add(Expression.IsNull("pe.PickupDate"))
            .Add(Expression.Eq("pe.PickupRequestSent", false))
            .Add(Expression.Eq("pe.MaintenanceRequestSent", false))
            .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);

        IList<Patients> patients = query.List<Patients>();

        if (patients == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return patients.Count();
```

Any ideas how I can get an accurate patient count without returning a full record set and then counting it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer....

```
 return FluentSessionManager.GetSession()
        .CreateCriteria<Patients>()
        .CreateAlias("Locations", "l")
        .CreateAlias("l.Branches", "b")
        .CreateAlias("PatientsEquipment", "pe")
        .Add(Expression.Eq("b.ID", branchID))
        .Add(Expression.Eq("CurrentStatus", Enumerations.PatientStatus.Inactive))
        .Add(Expression.IsNull("pe.PickupDate"))
        .Add(Expression.Eq("pe.PickupRequestSent", false))
        .Add(Expression.Eq("pe.MaintenanceRequestSent", false))
        .SetProjection(Projections.CountDistinct("ID")).UniqueResult<int>();
```

Apparently when I was using Projections.Count it was counting all records including duplicate.  When I changed it to CountDistinct that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add GroupProperty projection?  Like `Projections.GroupProperty(Projections.Property<Patients>(x => x.Id))`